# Does the existence of an associative, injective function imply the underlying set has only one element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

Assume we have a function $f: \Sigma \times \Sigma \to \Sigma$ sucht that $f$ is associative and injective. Does this imply $|\Sigma| = 1$? My reasoning is the following:

Let $x, y, z \in \Sigma$. By associativity we have $f(f(x, y), z) = f(x, f(y, z))$ and by injectivity $f(x, y) = x $ as well as $f(y, z) = z$. But since $x, y, z $ are arbitrary this implies: $\forall x, y \in \Sigma : f(x, y) = x \land f(x, y) = y$. 
So $\forall x, y \in \Sigma : x = y$ which would mean $|\Sigma| = 1$

Is this reasoning correct or did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: I think your proof is correct.

Comment: Your proof looks correct.

Comment: ... or $|\Sigma|=0$ ($\Sigma$ could also be empty)

Comment: As per @GeoffreyTrang's comment, you always have to watch out for that hidden assumption when you "Let $x,y,z\in \Sigma$ that such an element(s) actually exist

Comment: @GeoffreyTang Yes of course. Thank you. Let me add the assumption that $\Sigma$ has to be non-empty.  Then the statement must hold, right?